# dynamically show selected value in select list dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I created a Cascading of Dropdown list for Country state city in my application using Ajax request and Select Box. My application gathers information about users ie personal info etc. In my application there is an option to Edit the entered fields.. upon clicking the edit button the personal information page is populated with previously entered data. Now i need help to show the selected value that is which country, state and city is selected by the user in my select box dropdown. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

In your view assign the previously selected value to a javascript var. Then when the ajax request succeeds, set the dropdown value from the var.

Here's an example using jQuery.

```
// set a js var from a php var passed to the view from CI
var previous_country = <?=$previous_country?>;

$.ajax({
    // your ajax options here (url, datatype, etc)
    success: function(response){
        // code to populate dropdown here
        // then set the dropdown value to change the selected item:
        $('select#country').val(previous_country);
    }
});
```